# Cannot parse out substring between | characters in C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have a string that contains information separated by | characters, and I need to create substrings for each piece of information.  Additionally, some of the fields may be blank.

The order of values goes FirstName|LastName|Age|IDNumber|Height|Weight

So possible strings could be:

char* strA = "John|Doe|50|123456|70|150";
char* strB = "James|Smith|40|345678||";

I am able to pull out the first field just fine using sscanf, but when I attempt to grab multiple fields I get the wrong values.

In order to get the first value, I can call

```
char* strA = "John|Doe|50|123456|70|150";
char* a, b;
sscanf(strA, "%[^|]|", &a);
printf("%s\n", &a);
```

which prints
`John`
But when I attempt to get the first 2 fields by calling

```
char* strA = "John|Doe|50|123456|70|150";
char* a, b;
sscanf(strA, "%[^|]|%[^|]|", &a, &b);
printf("%s | %s\n", &a, &b);
```

It prints 
`oe | Doe`

I cannot figure out why that is.

Comment: The pointer a  char* a, b; is not initialized.

Comment: Don't use `&` when calling `printf`.

Comment: @Barmar that results in a segmentation fault for me

Comment: @VladfromMoscow but the values are set in the call to sscanf, why would it work when only looking for the first field but then break when looking for the first 2?

Comment: Your (a) lack of setting `a` and `b` to point to any valid memory, and (b) sending `a` and `b` *by address* (so the addresses of the pointers, not what they should be pointing to), are compounding your problems.

Comment: @SamHinkie You are wrong. The call of sscanf tries to write to the memory pointed to by the pointers but the memory was not allocated. Also using &a or &b is incorrect in the call.

Comment: @user3121023 You are right.:)

Comment: Note that incorrectly believing `char * a, b` declares two pointers is a primary motivator for two different stylistic points; move the * close to the name, and only declare one variable per line.  In other words, either `char   *a, b`  or `char *a; char b` make it painfully obvious that `b` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointer setup is wrong. Either use dynamic or automatic allocation. Also, your arguments to `sscanf` for format `%[^|]` are likewise wrong. That expects a `char*` and your delivering a `char**` in the `&a` case, and a simple pointer to `char` (one) in the `&b` case. *Both* should be referring to memory ample to consume your input.

**Example** (using automatic storage)

```
const char* strA = "John|Doe|50|123456|70|150";
char a[32], b[32];
sscanf(strA, "%31[^|]|%31[^|]|", a, b);
printf("%s | %s\n", a, b);
```

Frankly, nearly any modern toolchain worth its salt should have warned you of the improper types being sent to `scanf` and `printf`. Turn up your warnings and/or use a toolchain developed in this millennium.

Comment: What if I didn't want to predetermine the length of the fields? In your solution there is the potential for wasted memory since each field is allocated 32 characters worth of space. How could I do it more dynamically such that  a and b are the proper length?

Comment: @SamHinkie That's the *dynamic* option. And you're free to modify the operation as you deem necessary if that's how you want to approach this. It doesn't change the fact that the pointer setup was completely wrong from inception in the posted question.

Comment: @SamHinkie A better way would be to read the entire line in to a string (you can use `getline()` and it will size the string dynamically) and then use `strtok()` to split it at pipes.